# Google Calendar Feed / DOM not returning endTime correctly

Tags: php, dom, google-calendar-api

I'm collecting some basic stats from a Google Calendar feed with DOM and Php. I have been trying to get the event endTime using the following:

```
`$times = $entry->getElementsByTagName( "when" );
 $startTime = $times->item(0)->getAttributeNode( "startTime" )->value; 
 $endTime = $times->item(0)->getAttributeNode("endTime" )->value;`
```

Which results in an end time of 04:00:00 for every appointment.

I was trying different things and entered 1 instead of 0 in item() this results in a correct end time, but only three of the 50 appointments are displayed.

My feed is private, full, ordered by start time, singleevents=true, and start-min/start-max are set.

Is there a different way to get event endTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did find the answer to this question. Went ahead and went the Zend/Gdata route. Took a little to get up to speed but it works now.